# Frontend: Website / Shop Access Restricted To Registered Users

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, b2b

I am planning to create a multisite Magento store that may only be accessible to B2B customers.

- The users and user groups should be created via the backend, a registration via the frontend is not planned.
- Depending on the user group, the users should be redirected to a website assigned to the user group after successful login.
- Access to the Magento websites, on which products and prices are displayed, may only be visible to logged-in users.

Is this realizable with Magento 2.4 by default - and if so: how - or is an extension required?

Answer (score 0):

1. User and groups can be register from backend but in frontend need some customisation for block frontend registration.
2. After login user should redirect relevant/assigned website. It is also required customisation. No plugin are available for it.
3. For third point, visible price to logged in user. For this functionality have available extensions but i would recommend do it by customization because of it is hardly 20 or 30 min work.

Are you developer if no plz reply me i will help you.